# Temp Conversation fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am  trying to convert Temperature from fahrenheit to celsius and vice-versa. The ">>>>" which converts fahrenheit to Celsius doesn't function while the Celsius do Fahrenheit button functions. Please assist, I think I have been looking at the code for too long that's why I can't figure it out.

```
from Tkinter import *
   class Temp(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
 #               self._fahren = 0.0
 #               self._cel = 0.0
        self.master.title("TempConver")
        self.grid()
        self._fahrenLabel = Label(self, text="Fahrenheit")
        self._fahrenLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self._fahrenVar = DoubleVar()
        self._fahrenVar.set(32.0)
        self._fahrenEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self._fahrenVar)
        self._fahrenEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self._celLabel = Label(self, text="Celcius")
        self._celLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self._celVar = DoubleVar()
        self._celEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self._celVar)
        self._celEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self._fahrenButton = Button(self, text = ">>>>", command = self.FtoC)
        self._fahrenButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self._celButton = Button(self, text = "<<<<", command = self.CtoF)
        self._celButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    def FtoC(self):
        fahren = self._fahrenVar.get()
        cel = (5/9) * (fahren - 32)
        self._celVar.set(cel) 
    def CtoF(self):
        cel = self._celVar.get()
        fahren = (9/5) * (cel + 32)
        self._fahrenVar.set(fahren)



def main():
    Temp().mainloop()

    main()
```

Comment: Hard to guess what you mean by _doesn't function_ while lacking information. What I do notice is the calculation is wrong. It should be `cel = fahren * 5/9 - 32`.

Comment: @alvits Um, his formula is right.  Congrats on the upvote.

Comment: His formula for the other one is wrong ;)

Comment: @mwm314 Ah, yes, the one that OP said was working!

Comment: You've tagged the question with both python-2.7 and python-3.x, but one of the issues you may be having only applies in Python 2, so it really matters which version you're actually using. Can you please remove the version tag that doesn't actually apply?

Comment: @PaulCornelius - good catch. I didn't even bother to cross check. I just took his words that CtoF was working so logically, FtoC should be the reverse equation. The upvoter probably missed it that same way I did.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has to do with how division works in Python 2.

Compare:

```
a=(5/9)
b=(5/9.0)
```

In the first case, the result is an integer. In the second case, it is a float. If you divide two integers, it will return an integer that is rounded down, in your case to 0, resulting in a 0 answer in any case. If any of the two is a float, the result will be a float. In Python 3, either case will give the same float result.

This should work:

```
def FtoC(self):
    fahren = self._fahrenVar.get()
    cel = (5/9.0) * (fahren - 32)
    self._celVar.set(cel)
```

By the way, your conversion formula for Celsius to Fahrenheit is incorrect. First multiply by 9/5 before you add 32!
It should be:

```
fahren = ((9/5.0) * cel) + 32
```

Comment: You may want to note that integer division only works problematically in Python 2. In Python 3 (which the question is confusingly also tagged with), `5/9` works just fine.

Comment: @Blckknght True! I deduce from the Tkinter import (and not tkinter) the question was about python 2.